# grep multiple pattern with regex

Tags: bash, grep

Here is the text:

```
this is text this is text this is text this is text pattern_abc"00a"this is text this is text this is text this is textthis is text this is text pattern_def"001b"this is text this is text
```

in the output, I would like:

```
00a
001b
```

note: The values I look for are of random length and contents

I use 2 expressions:

```
exp_1 = grep -oP "(?<=pattern_abc\")[^\"]*"
exp_2 = grep -oP "(?<=pattern_def\")[^\"]*"
```

egrep does not work (I got "egrep: egrep can only use the egrep pattern syntax")

I try:

```
cat test | exp_1 && exp_2 
cat test | (exp_1 && exp_2) 
cat test | exp_1 | exp_2
cat test | (exp_1 | exp_2)
```

and lastly:

```
grep -oP "((?<=pattern_abc\")[^\"]* \| (?<=pattern_def\")[^\"]*)" test 
 grep -oP "((?<=pattern_abc\")[^\"]* | (?<=pattern_def\")[^\"]*)" test
```

Any idea? 
thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And another method through grep with Perl-regex option,

```
$ grep -oP '\"\K[^\"]*(?="this)' file
00a
001b
```

It works only if the string you want to match is followed by `"this`.

**OR**

You could use the below command which combines the two search patterns,

```
$ grep -oP 'pattern_abc"\K[^"]*|pattern_def"\K[^"]*' file
00a
001b
```

Comment: Thanks again Avinash; your tip is very interesting indeed; but is there any way to filter with _abc & _def

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `grep`,

```
grep -oP "(?<=pattern_(abc|def)\")[^\"]*" file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk -F\" '{for (i=2;i<NF;i+=2) print $i}' file
00a
001b
```

---

If the `pattern_*` is important you can use this `gnu awk` (due to `RS`)

```
awk -v RS="pattern_(abc|def)" -F\" 'NR>1{print $2}'
00a
001b
```